# How to import packages and class files in Library Project

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, apk-expansion-files

APK size has reached to `105 MB`, and i need to create `APK Expansion Files`.

I am following [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html?#Preparing) for creating Expansion Files.

I have downloaded `Google Play APK Expansion Library` and `Google Play Licencing Library`.

Now I need to add these libraries to my app.

I have followed [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#ExpansionPolicy). It states  following

1. Select File > New > New Module.
2. In the Create New Module window, select Android Library, and then
   select Next.
3. Specify an Application/Library name such as "Google Play License
   Library" and "Google Play Downloader Library", choose Minimum SDK
   level, then select Finish.
4. Select File > Project Structure.
5. Select the Properties tab and in Library Repository, enter the
   library from the /extras/google/ directory (play_licensing/ for
   the License Verification Library or
   play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/ for the Downloader Library).

Now the problem is in step-5:  When I add following the path in `Library Repository` it runs Gradle build for a while and then does nothing, and when I re-open the `Project structure` there is nothing in the `Library Repository field`.

> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\market_licensing\library

I am unable to understand how to import this project into my app. The other way is to individually copy each file and add it in the library module, but I don't want to try this approach.

**Project Structure :**

[image]

Comment: are you serious 105MB??

Comment: Yes it is. Our team will plan out to reduce the size, but for now we need to upload this build

Comment: Did you find silution?

Answer (score 2):

Use import module instead creation. For download module before improrting remove "android.library.reference.1=../market_licensing" line from project.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

In step 5 I entered this

<\sdk>/extras/google/market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/AndroidManifest.xml
for the downloader library and this
    <\sdk>/extras/google/market_licensing/library/AndroidManifest.xml
for the licensing library.

It seemed to accept these values.  The backslashes should be removed but that was the only way I could find to get the sdk inside of greater-than and less-than to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the library and there's a option to add as a library.You can add that as library by right clicking libs-> add as a library.

Comment: I have  added  an image. Please check it, and guide me  where to perform this  action.

Comment: right click on library option will appear to add as library